# What does Home Runs Allowed mean?

Tags: baseball, terminology

I am reading [an article](https://jtablesaw.wordpress.com/2016/07/31/play-moneyball-data-science-in-tablesaw/) about data science which uses some baseball statistics as an example. In it, there is the following phrase:

> we hypothesize that the number of wins can be predicted by the number of Runs Scored during the season, combined with the number of Runs Allowed

Wikipedia describes *Home* Runs Allowed as:

> ...home runs allowed (HRA) signifies the total number of home runs a pitcher allowed

However, that doesn't mean much to someone who doesn't really know baseball. What is the concept of allowing it to happen? Does a high value for Runs Allowed for a team mean that when it was pitching it permitted the batting team to get a lot of home runs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Runs" and "Home Runs" are two different terms.

A "home run" is a "run." A "run" isn't always a "home run."

According to the [2016 MLB Official Rules](http://mlb.mlb.com/mlb/downloads/y2016/official_baseball_rules.pdf), a "run" is:

> the score made by an offensive player who
>   advances from batter to runner and touches first, second, third and home
>   bases in that order.

---

> What does Home Runs Allowed mean?

A "home run" is<sub>[(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_run)</sub>:

> scored when the ball is hit in such a way that the batter is able to
>   circle the bases and reach home safely in one play without any errors
>   being committed by the defensive team in the process.

Typical usage is a fair ball that flies over the wall in the outfield, but there are instances in which the batter can still score a run in one play without doing this (called an "inside-the-park home run")<sub>[(2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inside-the-park_home_run)</sub>. "Home Runs Allowed" is the number of times the pitching team allows opposing batters to score a run in one play.

---

> What is the concept of allowing it to happen?

"Home Runs Allowed" is the number of times the pitching team allows opposing batters to score a run in one play. As you state in comments, "allowed" can be interchangeable with "conceded."

> Does a high value for Runs Allowed for a team mean that when it was pitching it permitted the batting team to get a lot of home runs?

Not necessarily. The batting team may have gotten a combination of singles, doubles, triples, walks, errors, etc. during an inning to score several runs. A [2011 game](https://patrickfloodblog.com/2011/06/26/14-runs-with-no-home-runs/) ([box score](http://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/TEX/TEX201106250.shtml)) shows the Mets scored 14 runs in a game without a home run.

Comment: wrt to my question of "not allowing it to happen" this is in reference to the fact that the Wikipedia article is about Home Runs _Allowed_. I'm beginning to think that in this context Allowed is interchangeable with Conceded.

Comment: @Rich That's accurate.